# Is there any size limit to %ProgramData%?

Tags: windows, directory-structure

I want to use **%ProgramData%** to store data of my application and have it available for all Windows users in the computer, while the actual application binary files will be stored in **%ProgramFiles%**.

I know that roaming app data amount is limited by `RoamingStorageQuota`, but I could not find any information regarding the folder I'm looking at.

Is there any limitation on the *total* amount of data that can be stored in **%ProgramData%**?

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer! Is there any link you know of that supports that statement?

Comment: http://superuser.com/